# HTML form submission, adding info to a list on the page

Tags: php, html, forms

I am writing an intranet site in HTML, and what online users to be able to add in their own infomation (such as skype name) so that I dont have to go through and add it all myself for the 1000 people at the company, and also so that when new starters come in, they can add their own infomation themselves.

I currently have a 'Users' page with a link in it to another page where there is a form code in it looking like this:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <title>Untitled Document</title>
     </head>

    <body>
     <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
     <label>Please type in a message
     <input type="text" name="msg" id="msg" />
     </label>
     <label>and your name
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
     </label>

     <p>
     <label>Submit
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
     </label>
     </p>
     </form>

     <?php
        $msg = $_POST["msg"];
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $posts = file_get_contents("users.html");
        $posts = "$msg - $name\n" . $posts;
        file_put_contents("users.html", $posts);
        echo $posts;
     ?>
```

I want the infomation users put into this form to be automatically put onto a list on the 'users.html' page, visible to everyone. I had hoped the above code would achieve this, but I cant get it to work.
Also, how would I specify whereabouts in the 'users.html' page the infomation is put? I want it to be amongst the:

```
  <div id="content">
    <div class="content_item">
```

..coding, so that it loads into a list inside the webpage.

Many Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to edit `users.html` with each submission. That way lies madness.

Store the submitted data in a database. Use the [PDO library](http://php.net/PDO) to do this.

Have the page that displays that data pull it from the database on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Although the use of database would be better and files tend to grow rather large with time, am answering your actual question as per your posted code.

To show the values that were written from a form (seperate from below), you could set up a page with this inside it:

```
<div id="content">
<?php echo file_get_contents("users.html"); ?>
<div class="content_item">
```

And the seperate page form would be like the following (tested)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Page Title Here</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<label>Please type in a message
<input type="text" name="msg" id="msg" />
</label>
<label>and your name
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
</label>

<p>
<label>Submit
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</label>
</p>
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && empty($_POST['msg']) && empty($_POST['name']) ) {
die("All fields need to be filled, please try again.");
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$msg = $_POST["msg"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$posts = $msg . "-" . $name;
$file = "users.html";
$fp = fopen($file, "a") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
fwrite($fp, $posts . "\n<br>") or die("Couldn't write values to file!");
fclose($fp);
}

echo $posts;
echo "<hr>Previous messages<hr>";
$file = "users.html";

if (file_exists($file)) {
$fp = file_get_contents($file, "r") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
echo $fp;
exit;
}

else {
echo "The file is empty";
}

?>
```